# error while using "django.contrib.auth.views.login"

Tags: django, authentication, django-login

i am getting error "view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()." while trying to use django's built-in Login system (login,logout,logout_then_login). can anyone please sort this out.

bookmarks/accounts/urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', 
name='logout_then_login'),
]
```

bookmarks/urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/',include("account.urls"))
]
```

templates/registration/login.html-

```
<body>

<h1>Log-in</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in.
{% endif %}

<div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url "login" %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>

</body>
```

templates/registration/logged_out.html-

```
<h1>Logged out</h1>
<p>You have been successfully logged out. You can <a href="{% url "login" 
%}">log-in again</a>.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using django>1.9: So you cannot use strings as views anymore. So you need to do something like this with all views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
#.....

    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
    ...
```

And also with the include:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/',include(urls))
]
```

Comment: `include()` function still accepts the modules as strings. Would you please remove that? That's completely unnecessary.